# global temporary table in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

In update mode of hbm2ddl.auto hibernate creates global temporary table like below,

```
Hibernate: create global temporary table HT_PASSENGER_VEHICLE (VEHICLE_ID number(10,0) not null) on commit delete rows
Hibernate: create global temporary table HT_TRANSPORTATION_VEHICLE (VEHICLE_ID number(10,0) not null) on commit delete rows
Hibernate: create global temporary table HT_VEHICLE (VEHICLE_ID number(10,0) not null) on commit delete rows
```

what are these tables? are these related to cache mechanism?
why hibernate creates these tables?

Comment: There is an [explanation by Steve Ebersole](http://in.relation.to/2005/07/20/multitable-bulk-operations/).

Comment: Hi @TobiasLiefke, thanks for the link but it is broken.

Comment: Not really, only the "http" protocol is turned off - just replace "http" with "https".

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate uses theses table for multi table bulk operations

see: https://in.relation.to/2005/07/20/multitable-bulk-operations/

> Both UPDATE and DELETE statements are challenging to handle against
>   single entities contained across multiple tables (not counting
>   associations), which might be the case with:
>
> - inheritence using `<joined-subclass/>`
> - inheritence using `<union-subclass/>`
> - entity mapping using the `<join/>` construct